# Sharded MongoDB Backup and Restore while using Bitnami Helm Charts

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, snapshot, bitnami, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm using Bitnami Sharded MongoDB Helm charts.

I need help on taking Backup of Data in Sharded Mongo and As we as to restore it again when needed.

I think its easy to do it with deployment file not with stateful set.

I have tried with VolumeSnapshot, But the problem is am able to create snapshots but not able to restore it with Bitnami Sharded MongoDB helm charts.

Answer (score 0):

were you using Velero for backing it up?

I'm able to restore a MongoDB instance "after disaster", i.e. on the same Namespace, but a full restore with *--namespace-mappings* (say, Helm release **mongo-store2** from **mongo2** to **mongo** Namespace) ends up needing subsequent patching:

- Of **Helm release Secret** and Helm-related annotations (several occurrences of the original Namespace)

```
A="$(kubectl get -o json secret/sh.helm.release.v1.mongo-store2.v1 | jq -r .data.release | base64 -d | base64 -d | gzip -dc |sed 's/mongo2/mongo/g'|gzip -c | base64 -w0 | base64 -w0)"

kubectl patch --type='merge' -p "{\"data\": {\"release\": \"${A}\"}}" secret/sh.helm.release.v1.mongo-store2.v1

for i in $(kubectl get -o name pod,service,deploy,replicaset,statefulset,secret,configmap,pvc -n mongo | grep -v -- kube-root)
do
  kubectl patch --type='merge' -p '{"metadata": {"annotations": {"meta.helm.sh/release-namespace": "mongo"}}}' $i
done
```

- Of **Deployment (mongos)** and **StatefulSets (configsrv, shard0, shard1)**, some environment variables reference the old Namespace

```
kubectl patch sts/mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-shard0-data --patch-file patch-shard0.yml
kubectl patch sts/mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-shard1-data --patch-file patch-shard1.yml
kubectl patch sts/mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-configsvr --patch-file patch-configsvr.yml
kubectl patch deploy/mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-mongos --patch-file patch-deploy.yml
```

with these patch files:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST
          value: mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-shard0-data-0.mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local
        - name: MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME
          value: $(MONGODB_POD_NAME).mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local
```

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST
          value: mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-shard1-data-0.mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local
        - name: MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME
          value: $(MONGODB_POD_NAME).mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local
```

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongos
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_CFG_PRIMARY_HOST
          value: mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-configsvr-0.mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-headless.mongokubectl .svc.cluster.local
```

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongodb
        env:
        - name: MONGODB_INITIAL_PRIMARY_HOST
          value: mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-configsvr-0.mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local
        - name: MONGODB_ADVERTISED_HOSTNAME
          value: $(MONGODB_POD_NAME).mongo-store2-mongodb-sharded-headless.mongo.svc.cluster.local
```

I've also tried restoring PVC/PVs only, reinstalling the Helm Chart on the destination Namespace (and saving me some patching, except those involving the *"meta.helm.sh/release-namespace"* annotation).

Either way, the **StatefulSets start up correctly**, but **mongos Deployments** stays **0/1** forever.